# Bootstrap Datatable Header is not aligned with body content in a Modal

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, datatable, bootstrap-modal

#### Screenshot

[image: This is my Screenshot]

This is my data table initialisation code:

```
$('#Table2').DataTable({
      
    scrollY:        "300px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
   'paging': false,
   'lengthChange': false,
   'searching': true,
   'ordering': true,
   'info': true,
   'autoWidth': true
});
```

My data table is created from server side cs code, below:

```
string _strDiv = string.Empty;
_strDiv = "<table id='tblSaleOrder' class='table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive dataTable no-footer' width='100%' style='font-size: small; width: 100%;' border='0' role='grid'>";
_strDiv += "<thead style='background-color: #3c8dbc;color: #f9f9f9;'>";
_strDiv += "<tr role='row'>";
_strDiv += "<td>Plant ID</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>QA #</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>SaleOrder #</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Material #</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Customer Code</td>";
//_strDiv += "<td>Customer Name</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Item #</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Line #</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Sale Order Date</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Quality/Type</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Description</td>";
_strDiv += "<td>Quantity</td>";
_strDiv += "<td align='center'>Action</td>";
_strDiv += "</tr>";
_strDiv += "</thead>";
_strDiv += "<tbody>";
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    _strDiv += "<tr>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PlantID"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["QAno"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SaleOrderNo"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MaterialNo"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CustomerCode"].ToString() + "</td>";
    //_strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CustomerName"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Item_no"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Line_no"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SaleOrderDate"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Quality"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["OrderQuantity"].ToString() + "</td>";
    _strDiv += "<td align='center'><button type='button' id='btnEditSaleOrder' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' data-matcode='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MaterialNo"].ToString() + "' data-sonum='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SaleOrderNo"].ToString() + "' data-tooltip='tooltip' title='Edit This Item' data-placement='top'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button></td>";
    _strDiv += "</tr>";
}
_strDiv += "</tbody>";
_strDiv += "</table>";
```

After sorting the table the column changes. ie., clicking on the header of my table it is automatically adjusting with tbody contents perfectly.

Comment: Can you create a working snippet/JS Fiddle - with some dummy data?

Comment: i cant coz the data is in server. i have used AdminLTE template also so i cant export everything to fiddle it.. im sorry

Comment: this issue happens only inside bootstrap Modals.

Comment: Shouldn't the table id be Table2 instead of tblSaleOrder?

Comment: can you show me your url?

Comment: it doesnt seem like you need your server side data to show this behaviour. Just create a fiddle with static placeholder data in the html tables to show the styling issue

Comment: its in localhost and i initialised datatable for 'tblSaleOrder' now also the same issue

Comment: i included a screenshot above all

Comment: We cant inspect the css of a screenshot ;) This is almost certainly a css clashing issue but we cant see what without an example

Comment: @solomonyelcin It probably has something to do with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` on the header row. But I can't confirm that without working code.

Comment: ok . i will create a fiddle and let u know. thx for now..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: See the linked-to duplicate. It is about a dataTable in hidden tabs but it is the same problem.  There is many, many similar questions, and it is explained and documented in the docs and on dataTables discussion forum like here  https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41830/header-not-align-or-scroll-in-bootstrap-modal simply use `columns.adjust()` when the modal is shown.

Comment: It ist NOT the same Question. The " question already has an answer here" is about a table inside a not visible tab. The solution do NOT work here, where the table is not inside a tab.  So my solution is to set per css a minimal width  `// Scroll-X
DIV.dataTables_scrollHeadInner,
DIV.dataTables_scrollFootInner{
 min-width: 100%;
}
DIV.dataTables_scrollHeadInner > TABLE,
DIV.dataTables_scrollFootInner > TABLE{
 min-width: 100%;
}`